# Simple reflections have determinant $-1$

Tags: reflection, root-systems

I have read that, given any root system $\Phi$ of a real Euclidean vector space $V$, every (simple) reflection $s_{\alpha} \colon V \to V$ has $$\det s_{\alpha} = -1.$$

I understand why $\det s_{\alpha}$ must be $\pm 1$: $s_{\alpha}$ satisfies $s_{\alpha}^2 = 1$. But why must its determinant be $-1$?

Comment: The determinant is a signed measure of how much the area of a given shape will change under a linear transformation. When you reflect the plane you “flip” the area of any shape, and so conventionally we say its area has been multiplied by $-1$. Compare the integral as the signed area of a curve (below the axis means the integral is negative)

Comment: The Special Orthogonal group is the set of rotations and reflections.  Rotations have determinant 1 and maintain orientation, reflections flip the orientation and have determinant -1

Comment: That I get, but can one actually show/calculate $\det s_{\alpha}=-1$ using perhaps a simple system $\Delta$ of $\Phi$?

Comment: Consider the transformation $T=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. This flips $\Bbb R^2$ about the $x$-axis and has $|T|=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easily seen that $s_\alpha$ is diagonalisable with eigenvectors $\pm 1$, where the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $-1$ is precisely 1-dimensional; from this, the claim follows.

Namely, I assume the definition of $s_\alpha$ is $s_\alpha(v) =v - \check{\alpha}(v)\cdot \alpha$ where $\check{\alpha} \in V^*$ with $\check{\alpha}(\alpha) =2$. Then

$s_\alpha(\alpha) = -\alpha$ and

$s_\alpha(v) = v$ for all $v \in \ker(\check{\alpha})$, which is a $(\dim V-1)$-dimensional subspace of $V$ (clear?).

Now if $(v_2, ..., v_n)$ is any basis of $\ker(\check{\alpha})$, then $(\alpha, v_2, ..., v_n)$ is a basis of $V$ (clear?) and with respect to that basis, $s_\alpha$ corresponds to the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $(-1, 1, ...., 1)$.

If your definition of $s_\alpha$ is different, the argument w.r.t. that definition should be just as easy.